# prevent change value in HTML page from Page Inspector

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I have a `combobox` with values in `UserEdit` page, to select the service that he want to use, but in this `combobox` he have only some service to choose,

```
<div class="editor-field">
  <select style="width:175px;" id="ServiceCode" name="ServiceCode">
      <option selected="selected" value="service1">service1</option>
      <option value="service2">service2</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

but I found that if the user use Page Inspector to change for example the selected service1 and edit it to service3 (and this was not in the `combobox`) but in confirmation this value (Service3 will be saved in database),

How can I prevent user to edit the values from HTML page or there's a way to check in server if element was changed in HTML page,

I have many problems like that; I just give a sample case,

Comment: You can't avoid the cliente modify the HTML before posting the form. But you can do some validations to ensure that the selected options is a valid value. If you have a list of thing to put in the select options, compare if the value returning is on that list, and return an error if don't. Another thing that you could use is ofuscate the values in form, with a code and you translate that value on server side and throw an error if it don't fits your pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to prevent the client from changing values in your form, because there are many ways to submit values for an HTTP form.

Therefore, you should always be validating the inputs against expected values, and rejecting unexpected values.

ASP.Net has some built-in validation for certain controls like dropdownlist and radiobuttonlist, for example.